# Efficiently concatenate fixed-size files together in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, concatenation

I'm working on a web application which requires very large files (several gigabytes) to be uploaded. We're using [resumable.js](http://resumablejs.com/) to upload the files. This library splits the file into chunks (by default 1024K) and uploads them; they then get reassembled on the server side. Currently, the part of the script that joins all of the chunks looks like this:

```
$fp = fopen('temp/'.$fileName, 'w');
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_files; $i++) {
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($temp_dir.'/'.$fileName.'.part'.$i));
}
fclose($fp);
```

This works great for smaller files (roughly 100 MB or so). However, when it tries to join larger files (multi-GB, with hundreds of chunks) it dies on the PHP script timeout partway through.

Is there a better/faster/more efficient way to concatenate the chunks together (potentially taking advantage of the fixed but configurable chunk size)?

Things I have considered:

- Shelling out to an external program which runs in the background and takes however long it needs to join the files. *This complicates the user interface, which has to know to wait until the file is ready.*
- Increasing the PHP timeout. *This is marginally better than the above, in that I don't have to poll to check if the file is ready. However, a large file will still take a long time.*
- Taking advantage of the fact that the chunks are usually uploaded in the correct order, and joining them together as they are uploaded. *This seems error-prone and requires additional bookkeeping. Uploading in order is not guaranteed, chunks may be uploaded more than once, and the server needs to be able to determine if a chunk has been uploaded yet.*

Comment: It is probably just a time issue: shell out that job to some other process then the webserver (some kind of job queue, there are loads of options, `gearman` being my favorite, `beanstalkd` being a very well known one), and let it report back when the 'build' has finished. Of course, if you're on Linux and not terribly worried about portability to other platforms, using `cat file >> newfile` may be a lot more efficient. Or [`dd`](http://superuser.com/questions/360462/whats-the-fastest-way-to-combine-two-or-more-files-in-linux)

Comment: @Wrikken: I suppose I _could_ use a job queue; this is a fairly small (internal) app and that seems like overkill though. My other concern is that while it's building the file, the progress bar on the UI is at 100% (all of the chunks have been uploaded) but the file isn't ready yet (thus confusing the user).

Comment: 100% uploaded bar, create a new bar => 'building' or 'processing' or something (in which you could possibly use the current chunk being processed, so you can actually show progress). But: `dd` is terribly fast compared to others, if you're on Linux or another POSIX system, and plan to keep being on POSIX systems, I'd give that a try first. on my crappy, crappy disk, [it does about 1GB/18.5 seconds](http://pastebin.com/uKSTqiun).